# Simple syntax error

Tags: java

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BasicCalculator
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int ADDITION = 1;
    int SUBTRACTION = 2;
    int MULTIPLICATION = 3;
    int DIVISION = 4;
    int EXIT = 5;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice;
    do
    {
      System.out.println("Choose from the following:");
      System.out.println("1. Add 2 integers");
      System.out.println("2. Subtract 2 integers");
      System.out.println("3. Multiply 2 integers");
      System.out.println("4. Divide 2 integers");
      System.out.println("5. Exit");
      System.out.print("Enter choice: ");
      choice = keyboard.nextInt();
      if ((choice == 1) || (choice == 2) || (choice == 3) || (choice == 4))
      {
        System.out.print("Enter first integer: ");
        int left = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter second integer: ");
        int right = keyboard.nextInt();
        switch (choice)
        {
        double Result;
        case 1: 
           Result = left + right;
          System.out.println(left + " + " + right + " = " + Result);
          break;
        case 2: 
           Result = left - right;
          System.out.println(left + " - " + right + " = " + Result);
          break;
        case 3: 
           Result = left * right;
          System.out.println(left + " * " + right + " = " + Result);
          break;
        case 4:
          Result = left / right;
          System.out.println(left + " / " + right + " = " + Result);
        }
        System.out.println();
      }
    } while (choice != 5);
  }
}
```

errors:

```
BasicCalculator.java:34: error: case, default, or '}' expected
        int Result;
        ^
BasicCalculator.java:34: error: case, default, or '}' expected
        int Result;
            ^
BasicCalculator.java:34: error: case, default, or '}' expected
        int Result;
```

the above code is my project for my intro to computer programming class,i've ran into a few errors that are stemming from formatting issues. can I get some basic help with whats causing the errors. I'm still trying to get used to reading the errors description in notepad++ and understanding what they mean.

Comment: What line is line 34?

Comment: You can't declare variables in a switch-statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm not sure this is completely correct as I don't really do Java, but here goes)
I think the error is where you have `double Result;` inside the switch statement - Java only allows either `case` or `default` inside the `switch` statement. Try placing the `double Result` line just above your `switch (...` line. Also, I'd make sure that all of the lines below your `case 1/2/3` statements are properly indented - it may just be the formatting on stack exchange, but the `Result = ...` lines look one character ahead (not sure if this would make a difference, but it's best to always have consistent code).

Comment: thanks for the clearing that up for me. its always the little things that throw me off. but thanks for taking the time for using the forum to help out daunted users like me. once again thanks!

Comment: @R.Isaac that's fine :), you'll always end up forgetting small details like that, everyone does it. you're welcome!

Comment: just as a note, @dasblinkenlight below has a good point too - they can be within the `case` part too, just not outside

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare a variable *inside* a `switch` statement outside of a `case` label. If you want `Result` to be shared among all `case`s, including the `default`, declare it prior to `switch`, like this:

```
double Result = 0;
switch (choice)
{
case 1: 
  Result = left + right;
  System.out.println(left + " + " + right + " = " + Result);
  break;
case 2: 
  Result = left - right;
  System.out.println(left + " - " + right + " = " + Result);
  break;
case 3: 
  Result = left * right;
  System.out.println(left + " * " + right + " = " + Result);
  break;
case 4:
  Result = left / right;
  System.out.println(left + " / " + right + " = " + Result);
}
```